# How do you calculate a probability given multiple probabilities?

Tags: probability

Assume that the following are the probabilities (P(S)) of runner's chance of finishing a race within S minutes

$$\begin{array}{|c|llll|}\hline S& 4& 6& 8& 9& 10\\\hline  
P(S)& .10& .40& .20& .15& .15\\\hline\end{array}$$

If there are 50 runners, what is the probability that none will take more than 7 minutes?

What kind of problem is this and how do I approach it?

Comment: Splitting the possible outcomes into two groups (up to 7 minutes and less than 7 minutes) makes this a binomial distribution problem. The sections called "Specification" and "Example" on the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) will give you an overview. If you're not familiar with the factorial of a number ($n! = n\cdot(n-1)\cdot(n-2)\cdot\dots\cdot(2)\cdot(1)$), you're basically just multiplying a bunch of numbers together. The result can get pretty big pretty fast, but otherwise the calculation shouldn't get too hairy.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the original problem is not worded very carefully. For example, if a runner makes it within 4 minutes then they also make it within 10 minutes, right?

It might be clearer to express the given information in terms of the running time for an individual runner $t$ as:

$$\begin{align}
P(t<0)&=0\\
P(0<t<4)&=0.10\\
P(4 < t < 6)&=0.40\\
P(6 < t < 8)&=0.20\\
P(8 < t < 9)&=0.15\\
P(9 < t < 10)&=0.15\\
P(t>10)&=0 
\end{align}$$

(With $t$ a continuous variable so $P(t=k)=0$ for any $k$ in the domain.)

Unfortunately, if we're interested in finding $P(t<7)$, we're going to have to make an *assumption* about how the probability is distributed in the $6<t<8$ region of the domain in order to make an educated guess.

For example, we might simply assume $P(6<t<7)=P(7<t<8)=0.10$. In this case, $P(t<7)=0.10+0.40+0.10=0.60$.

Now that we have the probability that a single runner will make it in under 7 minutes we can move on to the problem that all of 50 runners will make it under 7 minutes.

As mentioned in a previous answer, the number of runners who make it under 7 minutes (assuming independence, etc.) would be modeled using the binomial distribution:

$$X\sim\text B(50, 0.60)\Rightarrow P(X=x)={50\choose x}(0.60)^x(0.40)^{50-x}$$

where $X$ represents the number of runners who make it in under 7 minutes where the probability that any runner will make it in under 7 minutes is $0.60$.

For $x=50$ (the number of runners who make it under 7 minutes is all 50), this gives us:

$$P(X=50)=(0.60)^{50}=8.1\times 10^{-12}$$

(which is pretty darn close to impossible).

Answer (score 0):

First you identify the probability of one person finishing in less tha 7 minutes which would be if the finish in 4 or 6 minutes, the probability of this is .5

P(S<7) = P(4)+P(6) = 0.5

Now this is only for one person, so the next person would have also the same probability, so for both of them to finish in less than 7 minutes would be (.5)(.5) = .25 and so on

so for the fifty runners to finish in less than 7 mins it would be

(.5)^50 = 0.00000000000000088817842

Which means it's pretty unlikely that it happens

To better understand how unlikely it is, is like throwing a coin 50 times in a row and have the same result every time

Comment: how would i change the formula if I just want to find what's the prob of exactly one runner who ran under 7 minute?

Comment: The prob of one runner who ran under 7 mins is the first we calculated:"P(S<7) = P(4)+P(6) = 0.5"

Comment: But some runners may finish in less than 7 minutes and be in the $6 < t < 8$ group...